# In if (wspolczynnik > waga_linkow[n]) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I have two arrays: 
`wspolczynnik`
and 
`waga_linkow`

and I would like to enter the following instruction:

```
if (wspolczynnik > waga_linkow[n]){
  print('jest ok ')
} else {
  print('za male')
}
```

I get the following warning message:

```
[1] "za male"
Warning message:
In if (wspolczynnik > waga_linkow[n]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I correct the instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using the whole first vector, you need to add the [n] after both vectors in the if argument, for example:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4)
B <- c(0,0,1,5)
n <- 1

if (A[n] == B[n]){
  print('A equal to B')
} else {
  print('A not equal to B')
}
```

You could return results for all entries of the two vectors (I.e. A[1] and B[1], A[2] and B[2]...) writing a function and using a for loop

```
print_func <- function(a, b){
  if(a == b){
    print('a equal to b')
} 
if (a != b){
    print('a not equal to b')
}
}

for(i in 1:4){
  print_func(A[i], B[i])
}
```

However, my personal preference is to make a vectorised version.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4)
B <- c(0,0,1,4)
R <- rep("Not Equal", 4)
R[A == B] <- "Equal"
R
```

Comment: @nerson48 if this answers your question please accept the answer, if not clarify the question and I will adapt the answer to suit

Comment: @Nerson48 I've added a vectorised version